# Is there any performance difference between `df.add` and `series + series` in Polars

Tags: python-polars

Given data frame df, is there any meaningful performance difference between getting 2 `series` from it and doing `+` on them, vs. using chained `pl.Expr`s to do the same thing? I realize the resulting datatypes are different.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({'a':range(5), 'b':range(0,50,10)})

In [4]: df.get_column('a') + df.get_column('b')
Out[4]:
shape: (5,)
Series: 'a' [i64]
[
    0
    11
    22
    33
    44
]

In [5]: df.select(pl.col('a').add(pl.col('b')))
Out[5]:
shape: (5, 1)
┌─────┐
│ a   │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 0   │
│ 11  │
│ 22  │
│ 33  │
│ 44  │
└─────┘
```

Comment: In Polars, there is generally no significant performance difference between using df.add and series + series for basic arithmetic operations. Both approaches are likely to have similar performance because they achieve the same result using different syntax.

Comment: Try it. Generate a bunch of random numbers and time each operation.